# I need to know the switch IP

Tags: cisco

We are using More switches in our LAN setup,

We just want to know how many Switches we have crossed to reach the destination IP.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify. I don't understand the question.

Comment: No one can possibly know how many switches you cross without the network layout and your device in relation, and then just looking at the diagram would tell you. A better question might be, why would this matter, and explaining that might help clarify what you are asking.

Comment: You could improve your question by editing it to add more details. You may find our [Question Checklist](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/292/33) helpful when editing your question.

Comment: I found his question easy to understand.  Why all the downvotes?  This is not an uncommon need.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

If the switches are without management, you cant know because they are blind, meaning they wont/arent being treated as a node/hop like routers are

Comment: Managed switches are not treated as hops; the management IP is almost never involved in the frame switching or the routing.  If it was, it'd be a router.

Answer (score 1):

Easy, provided you have access to these networking devices (switches).  Log in and ask it to tell you who it's layer 2 neighbors are.  If Cisco that's `show CDP neighbor` and if not it's probably `show LLDP neighbor`.

Adding the `detail` keyword to the end of that command will tell you the IP address of the networking device it sees.  Telnet/SSH into that device and repeat.  This will give you a layout.

`show arp` and see the mac address of the IP address and then `show mac address table` and trace it home.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question, and it's Cisco, you can use:

```
traceroute mac ip source-ip-addr dest-ip-addr
```

This requires CDP enabled on all the switches.
Of course source-ip-addr and dest-ip-addr must belong to the same subnet.